# How to download file from local server in Python

Tags: python, sockets, server

Scenario is:

1. Client will Enter a file name  e.g **xyz**
2. Server will show all the files that it have in different folders.

Client will select 1 or 2 or 3 (if there). 
and file will be downloaded.

**I have done searching part.  I want help in downloading and saving the file in any other directory.**

My code so far is for searching the file.

```
import socket
tcp_ip="127.0.0.1"
tcp_port=1024
buffer_size= 200
filename=raw_input("Enter file name\n")

s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((tcp_ip,tcp_port))
data=s.recv(buffer_size)
s.close()
```

Server Code : (This code is now for one file) **The required help is how to download and save that file which is found at server.**

```
import socket
import os
tcp_ip='127.0.0.1'
tcp_port=1024
buffer_size=100
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((tcp_ip, tcp_port))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection Address:',addr
while 1:
    data=conn.recv(buffer_size)
    if not data: 
        break
    else:
        print "received server side data:", data
    conn.send(data)
conn.close()
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're not using HTTP for this?

Comment: i have to do it using tcp.

Comment: HTTP works over TCP.

Comment: What would be solution for Http ?

Comment: remember for localhost (loopback interface) the payload size is 65K (MTU) unlike an ethernet 1500 bytes (typically, Jumbo cables can transmit 9K bytes) MTU. So you can increase buffer size here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following is the example which shows how to download a file from a server over tcp.

Client Code:

```
import socket
import os

HOST = 'localhost'    
PORT = 1024
downloadDir = "/tmp"


filename = raw_input('Enter your filename: ')
socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket1.connect((HOST, PORT))
socket1.send(filename)
with open(os.path.join(downloadDir, filename), 'wb') as file_to_write:
    while True:
        data = socket1.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        file_to_write.write(data)
    file_to_write.close()
socket1.close()
```

Server Code:

```
import socket
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 1024

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
socket.listen(1)
while (1):
    conn, addr = socket.accept()
    reqFile = conn.recv(1024)
    with open(reqFile, 'rb') as file_to_send:
        for data in file_to_send:
            conn.sendall(data)
    conn.close()

socket.close()
```

Note: server code is not robust and will crash when file doesn't exists. You should modify above example according to your needs.

Comment: what is file name here ?  at server side ? I am new in Python

Comment: can i chat with u ?  or some thing ? help is about this code that u posted. file is downloding but empty.

Comment: can you provide information on your test case? The file you are trying to download must be present on the server.

Comment: We are chatting here on stackoverflow. If you think you may not be able to explain the issue in comment, then post a new question providing all the details. This will ensure that everybody else on stackoverflow can analyze the problem & provide suggestions.