# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'

Tags: python-3.x

I run this script

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket

def snd():
    a = ent.get()
    sock.send(a.encode())
    print("Отправка текста")
def sndfle():
    b = ent2.get()
    file = open(b, "rb")
    sock.send(file)
    print("Отправка файла")


sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 25565))
print ("Соединение с сервером установлено")
```

I see this error

```
    sock.send(file)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'
```

Please help me
I run def(s) with buttons. I hide it.

Comment: does `sock.send(file).read()` do the trick?

Comment: No, it isn`t works

Comment: oops, sorry, that should have read `sock.send(file.read())` of course...

Comment: And it isn`t works...

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110620/how-to-download-file-from-local-server-in-python).

You need to get bytes from the file in order to send it over the socket. Try this:

```
def sndfle():
    b = ent2.get()
    with open(b, "rb") as file:
        for data in file:
            sock.sendall(data)
    print("Отправка файла")
```