# Downloading entire file over TCP client/server function in python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to create a function that downloads files from a client to a server.

I followed the top answer on this question:
[How to download file from local server in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110620/how-to-download-file-from-local-server-in-python)

Unfortunately my code runs in a infinite loop.
Here is the client:

```
def upload(file):
        with open(file, 'rb') as f:
           for data in f:
              c.sendall(data)
           f.close()
```

server side code:

```
def download(filename):
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            buff = csock.recv(1024)
            if not buff:
                break
            f.write(buff)
        f.close()
```

Comment: You forgot to close `c` in the sender, not to mention `csock` in the receiver, so the `break` never happened.

Comment: I see, I cannot close the connection because it will drop the connection to the server, should I use a different protocol (socket object) for this operation?

Comment: Why can't you drop the connection to the server? That's the only way the `break` is ever going to execute.